# Perl: Problem with changing encoding in the middle of reading a file

Tags: perl, encoding, binmode

I am using Perl to load some 'macro' files. These macros can, however, be encoded in various encodings, so there is a directive defined for users writing their macros (i.e.

```
#encoding iso-8859-2
```

at the beginning of the macro).

Every time this directive is encountered in the macro, a function setting encoding is called and looks sth like this:

```
sub change_encoding {
  my ($file_handle, $encoding) = @_;
  $file_handle->flush();
  binmode($file_handle);           # get rid of IO layers
  binmode($file_handle,":encoding($encoding)");
}
```

The problem is that when I read the macro using standard

```
while($line = <$file_handle>){
  process_macro($line);
}
```

I got messages saying "utf8 "\xXY" does not map to Unicode", but only if characters with diacritics is near the #encoding directive. I tried several examples and I was able to have half of the string with \xXY codes and other half of the string with correctly decoded characters, like here:

```
sub macro5_fn {
  print "\xBElu\xBBou\xE8k\xFD k\xF9\xF2 úpěl ďábelské ódy\n";
}
```

If I put more comments before the function, all the characters are OK:

```
sub macro5_fn {
  print "žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy\n";
}
```

Simply said, the number of correctly decoded characters depends on the distance of these characters from the #encoding directive, the ones that are close are not decoded correctly.

It seems to me that this is an issue of Perl and PerlIO (not) flushing the buffer. Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: maybe I should have mentioned that all the macros are opened just with 
`open($file_handle, '<', $macro_name)`
and then set to default encoding by calling `change_encoding($fh,"utf8")`

Comment: have you tried keeping the handles in byte mode and then decoding into the correct character format using `$chars = Encode::decode($encoding, $bytes)`? That should sidestep any buffering issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `<>` reads more than just one line, so the next line or so is being interpreted under the old encoding before you ever see the `#encoding` directive for the new.

Your best bet is probably to read the file in binary mode and use the Encode module to decode each line from the current encoding.